# Transpose data from rows to column in mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot, pivot-table, transpose

I have very limited knowledge in mySql yet i try to help myself by reading stuff over internet and experiment things. I have a situation where i need to pivot/transpose data from rows to column. I have prepared a set of statements which is working perfectly fine as SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when field_name = ''',
      field_name,
      ''' then field_value end) ',
      field_name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  wp_fluentform_entry_details;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT submission_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM wp_fluentform_entry_details 
                   GROUP BY submission_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Now i want to save it as view in mysql but unable. Any guidance in right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: thankyou Strawberry, let me give it a try

Comment: For Pivoting in MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831